# Magento calls not happening when calling from inside a function

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create a user in Magneto using XMLRPC inside PHP. The call is successful when calling it directly from a page, however, if I place the same call inside a function, it is not happening at all. Any ideas?

Code directly on page: [ Working perfect]

```
<?php 
require 'Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php';
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('myclient.com/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array('myuser', 'mypass'));
$new_customer =  array('email' => 'nasr@di91.com','firstname' => 'Nair','lastname' => 'Perwaiz','password' => '123456','website_id' => 1,'store_id' => 1,'group_id' => 1);
$zendSpecificArray =array(Zend_XmlRpc_Value::getXmlRpcValue($new_customer,Zend_XmlRpc_Value::XMLRPC_TYPE_STRUCT));
$rArray = array($session,'customer.create',$zendSpecificArray);
$new_customer_id = $client->call('call',$rArray);
$rtnval='<?xml version="1.0"?>'.PHP_EOL;
$rtnval.='<root>'.PHP_EOL;
$rtnval.='<result>'.'Customer created with ID :'.$new_customer_id .'</result>'.PHP_EOL;
$rtnval.='</root>'.PHP_EOL;
$client->endSession($session);
header('Content-Type:','Application/xml');
echo $rtnval;
?>
```

Code inside the function: [No output being received]

```
function registerUser($email,$firstname,$lastname,$password)
{
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('myclient.com/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array('myuser', 'mypass'));
$new_customer =  array('email' => $email,'firstname' => $firstname,'lastname' => $lastname, 'password' => $password,'website_id' => 1,'store_id' => 1,'group_id' => 1);
 $zendSpecificArray =array(Zend_XmlRpc_Value::getXmlRpcValue($new_customer,Zend_XmlRpc_Value::XMLRPC_TYPE_STRUCT));
$rArray = array($session,'customer.create',$zendSpecificArray);
$new_customer_id = $client->call('call',$rArray);
$rtnval='<?xml version="1.0"?>'.PHP_EOL;
$rtnval.='<root>'.PHP_EOL;
$rtnval.='<result>'.'Customer created with ID :'.$new_customer_id .'</result>'.PHP_EOL;
$rtnval.='</root>'.PHP_EOL;
$client->endSession($session);
header('Content-Type:','Application/xml');
echo $rtnval;
}
```

Call : `http://localhost/xxx/rpcclient/rpc.php?methodname=registeruser&em=uuuy@gmail.com&f=ab&l=ty&p=kaddoo`

Comment: I may be stating the obvious here, but are you calling `registerUser(...)` somewhere in the code? If so please add that code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran a wireshark trace and found that my program was not catching the fault. SO fixed it. Thanks a lot everyone!